# Hide port number of Socket IO app using htaccess file in apache

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, socket.io

I have a node js socket io chat application running on port 1234 and I want the url `www.example.com/chat` to hit `www.example.com:1234/chat` using the htaccess file.
I have it set up where the chat application shows up but socket IO does not actually work, I get a `socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1447797482690`
Currently I am using Pm2 to deploy the node.js apps.  Im not sure if it is socketio that has a bug or maybe I am just missing something in my code. Any help is appreciated.

Heres the htacces:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com:1234/ [P,L]
```

And index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/chat', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});
http.listen(1234, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:1234');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do than with this code:

in .htaccess:

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteRule ^/?socket.io http://localhost:58000/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

and in my file.js:

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs');

var app = http.createServer(function (request, response) 
{
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Notif.js RESPONSE');
}).listen(XXXXX);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) 
{ 
    console.log('New Connection from '+remoteAddr+':'+remotePort);

    socket.on('message_to_client', function(data)  //message_to_server_connection
    { 
        var message2 = "Mensaje from server: "+data["message"];  //sanitize(data["message"]).escape();  //
        io.sockets.emit("message_to_client",
        { 
            message: message2 
        });              
    });
    socket.on('message_to_server_connection', function(data)  //message_to_server_connection
    { 
        io.sockets.emit("message_to_client",
        { 
            message: "Connected...... ";
        }); 
    });
});

console.log('WebSocket Server listening on localhost:XXXXX');
```

When i write in the browser address bar http://..../socket.io, nodejs response is the correct:

```
  Notif.js RESPONSE
```

My problem is how to write de javascript code to connect to nodeJS avoiding write the true destination port:

```
        var socketio= io.connect("localhost:XXXXX");            

        socketio.on("connect", function(data) 
        {
            socketio.emit("message_to_server_connection", 
            { 
                message : "Connected"
            });
        });
```

so i want route this traffic  through port 80